# Spring framework: lifecycle callback concept

Tags: spring, callback, lifecycle

I am trying to understand the concept of `lifecycle` and `callback` in Spring framework. I did search in SO, for example [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469369/what-do-you-mean-by-callbacks)

I am still not clear on this, are these terms viz: `life-cycle` and `callback` one and same thing or are they two different concepts?

Can anyone help me clarify this?

Comment: lifecycle: what happens during the life of something, from the moment it's created until it's destroyed. Callback: a method that you create and that is called by the framework. Lifecycle callback: a method that you create and that is called by the framework at specific moments of the life of a bean.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks for your reply. So, as I understand these are generic concepts, not necessarily tied up to Spring Framework. And during various "phases" of object , methods which are (automatically) called by framework are referred to as "callbacks". Now, if I understood this corrects, it reminds me of some EJB 2.x methods like: ejbActivate(), ejbPassivate().. Did I understood correct?

Comment: You got it right. They're indeed the same kind of things as ejbActivate.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks again, for your help; I wish you had written as answer and I would have accepted by now. Thanks a ton!