# Java 8 lambda (from javascript example)

Tags: javascript, java, lambda

I'm learning java from javascript background, and I wonder is it possible to write similar function in Java. Here is an example in javascript:

```
function getBalance(side, date) {
    let balance;
    let getPrice = (f) => {
        while ((result = f(date)) == 0) {
            date++;
        }
        return result;
    }
    if (side) {
        let price = getPrice(getPrice1);
        // Some calculations
        return balance;
    } else {
        let price = getPrice(getPrice2);
        // Some calculations
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Where getPrice1 and getPrice2 are previously defined functions. Use of calbacks here helps to keep code short. Im not sure is it possible in Java to pass function as argument without declaring additional interfaces.

I asked this question because it is a simplified example of a real task that I encountered. What do you think will be the most elegant solution?

P.S. Looks like Functional Interfaces is the way here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405421/what-is-a-callback-method-in-java-term-seems-to-be-used-loosely -see this

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for functional interfaces?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a callback method in Java? (Term seems to be used loosely)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405421/what-is-a-callback-method-in-java-term-seems-to-be-used-loosely)

Comment: IMO Java coders are more used to rely on OOP in contrast to Javascript coders which are more used to rely on functional code. While the accepted answer show you a parallel which would definitely work, in my experience such code will rarely be found in enterprise code. What you would usually find is a `getPrice` method accepting an instance of an interface and calling a method defined by that interface, which would be implemented in a different way in two different classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Here's a dummy showcase just to illustrate how things can be put together.

```
class Showcase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<Function<LocalDate, Double>, Double> getPrice = f -> {
            // an example how to call it - replace it with your logic
            f.apply(LocalDate.now());

            return 0.;
        };

        getPrice.apply(Showcase::getPrice1);
        getPrice.apply(Showcase::getPrice2);
    }

    public static Double getPrice1(LocalDate date) {
        return 0.;
    }

    public static Double getPrice2(LocalDate date) {
        return 1.;
    }

}
```

It would be more verbose because of the typing discipline. However, the idea is fundamentally the same.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that looks quite close to the javascript code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Showcase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

        double result1 = getPrice(priceFunction1, date);
        double result2 = getPrice(priceFunction2, date);
    }

    private static double getPrice(PriceFunction priceFunction, LocalDate date) {
        return priceFunction.getPrice(date);
    }

    private static final PriceFunction priceFunction1 = date -> date.getYear() * 0.5;
    private static final PriceFunction priceFunction2 = date -> date.getYear() * 1.5;

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface PriceFunction {
        double getPrice(LocalDate date);
    }
}
```

Instead of using the standard functional interfaces from the java language, like `Function`, simply define a new functional interface that exactly fulfills the requirements of your function: it takes a date and returns a double value.

The getPrice function takes such a 'function' as the first argument, then we have to pass the date (javascript scopes make it a bit easier there...). The 'functions' themselves are lambda expressions and we can store them as fields or static constants.

The purist may scream that I didn't choose a screaming case for the names, but I'd deviate from the common naming conventions on purpose for the sake of readability.